# ASP.NET identity with mysql instead of SQL Server null reference

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to use the ASP.NET Web API to work with MySQL. I followed the steps described in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

So what I did was the following:

1. Install the mysql connector and created a mysql database locally via workbench
2. Add the reference to `mysql.data` to the project
3. Via nuget manager the `mysql.data.entity` installed
4. The config did automatically added the mysql provider

Config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
        </provider>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

5. I added the class `MySqlInitializer`:

   ```
   public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
   {
       public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           if (!context.Database.Exists())
           {
               // if database did not exist before - create it
               context.Database.Create();
           }
           else
           {
               // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
               var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
                 "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'IdentityMySQLDatabase' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'");

               // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
               if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
               {
                   context.Database.Delete();
                   context.Database.Create();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. I changed the `ApplicationDbContext` to:

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       static ApplicationDbContext()
       {
           Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
       }

       public ApplicationDbContext()
         : base("DefaultConnection")
       {
       }

       public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
       {
           return new ApplicationDbContext();
       }
   }
   ```

My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Database=IdentityMySQLDatabase;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=Admin!@#" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm using advanced rest client to test the api. But when I want to register a new user I get a null reference. This is my stacktrace:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3 k)
>
>   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.d__67.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2.<ValidateAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__73.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<CreateAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   TestMYSQL.Controllers.AccountController.d__20.MoveNext() in
>   D:\Visual Studio
>   Projects\Private\TestMYSQL\TestMYSQL\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line
>   333 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated. I have searched for a 2 days now and still no success of solving the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After researching the possibilites. The solution was simpler then I thought. If someone, had the same problem here is what I did:
- Add new project mvc with identity for individual users login.
- Install nuget package Mysql.Data
- Install nuget package Mysql.Data.EntityFramework
- Create your own mysql database and get the connection string.
- Change the connection string and add the providername 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'

Startup and register a username, the application creates a database in mysql for you.

I hope this well help someone who encountered the same problems.